# Override the 'is' functionality

Tags: c#

I have a class so contains a exception, as so.

```
public class ExceptionWrapper
{
    public string TypeName { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string InnerException { get; set; }
    public string StackTrace { get; set; }

    public ExceptionWrapper() { }

    public ExceptionWrapper(Exception ex)
    {
        TypeName = String.Format("{0}.{1}", ex.GetType().Namespace, ex.GetType().Name);
        Message = ex.Message;
        InnerException = ex.InnerException != null ? ex.InnerException.Message : null;
        StackTrace = ex.StackTrace;
    }

    public bool Is(Type t)
    {
        var fullName = String.Format("{0}.{1}", t.Namespace, t.Name);
        return fullName == TypeName;
    }
}
```

I want to override the 'is' action, So instead of doing so

```
if (ex.Is(typeof(Validator.ValidatorException)) == true)
```

I will do so

```
if (ex is Validator.ValidatorException)
```

Is it possible? How?

Comment: You can remove the `== true` part anyway since your `Is` method returns a `bool`. Also the method name indicates that the return value would be a boolean value so there is no need to clarify it via an explicit check for `true`.

Comment: It is not cool to compare types through comparing their name strings. The usual thing to do is `a is MyType` if you want to test if `a` has a run-time type compatible with `MyType` through inheritance (including boxing/unboxing) or generic variance. If you want to check for an exact run-time type, use instead `a != null && a.GetType() == typeof(MyType)`. As I said, don't compare strings.

Comment: @Jeppe I can't get the original type of the error, because it is transfer in this wrapper class via WCF.

Comment: You can keep `ex.GetType()` itself instead of keeping a string built up from `ex.GetType().Namespace` and `ex.GetType().Name`. When the inner exception is not null, you can also keep `ex.InnerException.GetType()`.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

From [Overloadable Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the following operators can be overloaded:

- Unary: `+, -, !, ~, ++, --, true, false`
- Binary: `+, -, *, /, %, &, |, ^, <<, >>`
- Comparison: `==, !=, <, >, <=, >=`

And these operators cannot be overloaded:

- Logical: `&&, ||`
- Array Indexing: `[]`
- Cast: `(T)x`
- Assignment: `+=, -=, *=, /=, %=, &=, |=, ^=, <<=, >>=`
- Others: `=, ., ?:, ??, ->, =>, f(x), as, checked, unchecked, default, delegate, is, new, sizeof, typeof`

Also, comparison operators need to be overloaded in pairs, if you overload one, you must overload the other:

- `==` and `!=`
- `<` and `>`
- `<=` and `>=`

Comment: IMHO, `Is != is`. It is like creating a new function `Is()` and not overloading the `is` operator. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Since when you cannot overload the Cast operator?
[explicit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4.aspx) and [implicit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx)

Answer (score 33):

The straight answer is: No, `is` cannot be overridden (because it is a keyword).

But you could do something more elegant by using generics. First define your `Is()` method like so:

```
public bool Is<T>() where T: Exception
{
    return typeof(T).FullName == this.TypeName;
}
```

Then you can write your comparison like this:

```
if (ex.Is<Validator.ValidatorException>())
```

Answer (score 11):

`is` is a non-overloaded keyword, but you can write extensions method like this:

```
public static bool Is<T>(this Object source) where T : class
{
   return source is T;
}
```

Comment: How is your example useful? Saying `mySource.Is<MyType>()` is not nicer than saying `mySource is MyType`. Another question: Why would you constrain to `class`, i.e. reference types?

Comment: is useful because the method extends the object and can be called on any object. It is therefore common. Limited to class is perhaps unnecessary, an example I copied from a project where I needed this restriction.

Comment: I don't understand. If you have the code `var myCar = new Car(); bool test = myCar is Giraffe;`, and neither of the types `Car` and `Giraffe` is an interface type, then if `Car` is not in the inheritance chain of `Giraffe` and `Giraffe` is not in the inheritance chain of `Car`, then the `is` keyword leads to a compile-time warning. But that is a good thing. You could get around that with `(object)myCar is Giraffe`, or with your extension, but the value will still be `false` always. So using `is` is better than using your extension.

Comment: Maybe you are right that "is" is useful for warning at compile time, but it certainly depends on the type of project. In my case, I have a full assembly of different extensions and use it in most of the projects. I've never gotten that sometimes failed and missed me a warning in compile-time.